# android instagram video download using webview

Tags: java, android, video, instagram

I am trying to download an instagram video using a webview, but it doesn't even detect the video that I am trying to download. I tried that code to download facebook videos and it works just fine, but for instagram when I click the video I expect it to open on a separate page, but it doesn't and it can't download.

**below is the code i tried:**

```
public void downloader()
    {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


   /* if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }*/


            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                    + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                    + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                    + "{"
                    + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                    + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                    + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'IGDownloader.processVideod(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\");');"
                    + "}" + "}" + "})()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                    + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                    + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                    + "{"
                    + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                    + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                    + "console.log(i);"
                    + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                    + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'IGDownloader.processVideod(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"
                    + "}" + "}" + "})()");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo;"
                    + ")()");
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: It might be better to just download the html text of the page itself, then use String functions like `indexOf` to search for `<video>` text and from that position, the following `src=` up to `.mp4` text. That will be the link. Also I think the `<og>` tags in the html have the mp4 link also but I can't remember. If still stuck then provide an example InstaGram link to check.

Comment: could it be *IGDownloader.processVideod* needs to be *IGDownloader.processVideo* without the last *d*  ?